# Python - Generate PDF from created Excel workbook - cannot save pdf document

Tags: python, excel, pdf, openpyxl

I am trying to generate a PDF file from .xlsx worbook.
At first, I'm creating a new workbook with data from another one (with some extra data conversion).
Then, I'm saving new workbook into temp path.
Then, I want to open created .xlsx and save it as PDF file.

But when I'm trying to save it, I am getting this message:

```
Błąd: (-2147352567, 'Wystąpił wyjątek.', (0, 'Microsoft Excel', 'Nie zapisano dokumentu. Być może jest on otwarty lub przy zapisywaniu napotkano błąd.', 'xlmain11.chm', 0, -2146827284), None)
```

(it is in polish)
`The document was not saved. Perhaps it is open or an error was encountered when saving it`

Without code, that is supposed to save a .pdf file, .xlsx file is creating correctly.

Code of my program:

```
import sys
import openpyxl
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl.drawing.image import Image
from openpyxl.utils import get_column_letter
from tkinter.filedialog import asksaveasfile
import os
from win32com import client

initialFile = sys.argv[1]
initialCatalog = sys.argv[2]
assetsCatalog = f"{initialCatalog}\\api\\assets"

def codeToPictogram(code):
  for files in os.walk(assetsCatalog):
      if f'{code}.png' in files[2]:
          return 1
      else:
          return 0

try:
    wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(initialFile)
    ws = wb.active
    ws.title = "Stan techniczny nawierzchni"

    for row in ws.iter_cols(min_row=2, min_col=2, max_row=ws.max_row, max_col=ws.max_column):  
        for cell in row:  
            if(cell.value is None):
                continue
            if (codeToPictogram(cell.value) == 1):
                img = Image(f"{assetsCatalog}\\{cell.value}.png")
                img.height = 100
                img.width = 100
                ws.add_image(img, f"{get_column_letter(cell.column)}{cell.row}")
    file = asksaveasfile(defaultextension='.pdf',title = 'Zapisz stan techniczny', filetypes=[("Plik PDF", "*.pdf")])
    if file is not None:
        wb.save(f'{initialCatalog}\\api\\temp\\temp.xlsx')
        # wb.close()
        
        excel = client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
        sheets = excel.Workbooks.Open(f'{initialCatalog}\\api\\temp\\temp.xlsx')
        work_sheets = sheets.Worksheets[0]
        work_sheets.ExportAsFixedFormat(0, file.name)
        
        print("Gotowe!")
        input("Wciśnij Enter, aby zamknąć...")
except Exception as e:
    print(f"Błąd: {e}")
    input("Wciśnij Enter, aby zamknąć...")
```

I tried to use `wb.close()`, but without any success.
I was looking through openpyxl documentation, but I did not found any way to save new workbook as .pdf without saving it as a .xlsx firstly.

It is my first attempt to do a Python application, so maybe there is something stupidly simple, that I don't know.
I'm trying to adapt from C# :)

I'd appreciate any help

Comment: Why close and reopen the file? Can you not save it as .xlsx without closing, then export as PDF while it's still open? And if your goal is just the PDF, can you skip the temp.xlsx and just export as PDF? 

I can't help with the Python, I'm weak on that side.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have two main issues

1. `asksaveasfile` creates a `textIowrapper`,the pdf file is created by the command and cannot be overwritten resulting in an error.
2. You may not be reading the correct sheet to convert to pdf

Either way I believe your code bombs out when trying to write the pdf since the named pdf at that time is an **open file**.
You want a string for file name so try changing `asksaveasfile` to `asksaveasfilename` which will not create a file and returns a string. Or since you are using win32com anyway, use `GetSaveAsFilename`

The following code sample modifies your code;

1. Changes the file name request to use the win32com `GetSaveAsFilename`
2. Sets `work_sheets` to the named sheet `"Stan techniczny nawierzchni"`
3. Closes the win32 client
4. Deletes the temp xlsx file (optional)

This code sample successfully creates the pdf and deletes the temp xlsx file leaving no zombie Excel process.

```
...
    # file = asksaveasfile(defaultextension='.pdf', title='Zapisz stan techniczny', filetypes=[("Plik PDF", "*.pdf")])
    ### Change file name input
    samplefilename = 'PDF_Filename.pdf'
    excel = client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
    file = excel.GetSaveAsFilename(samplefilename,
                                   FileFilter="PDF Files (*.pdf), *.pdf",
                                   Title='Zapisz stan techniczny')

    if file is not None:
        wb.save(f'{initialCatalog}\\api\\temp\\temp.xlsx')

        sheets = excel.Workbooks.Open(f'{initialCatalog}\\api\\temp\\temp.xlsx')
        ### Be sure the sheet you are saving is the right one
        work_sheets = sheets.Worksheets["Stan techniczny nawierzchni"]
        work_sheets.ExportAsFixedFormat(0, file)
        ### Close the win32 instance
        sheets.Close(True)

        ### Now you can remove the xlsx file
        os.remove(f'{initialCatalog}\\api\\temp\\temp.xlsx')

        print("Gotowe!")
        input("Wciśnij Enter, aby zamknąć...")
except Exception as e:
    print(f"Błąd: {e}")
    input("Wciśnij Enter, aby zamknąć...")
```

Answer (score -1):

The issue is temp.xlsx is not closing Excel. Excel is still active and has a file lock on it. So when you're trying to write to it, the file is locked.

I'm not sure on the resolution to this, but you can try out pandas for this use case, instead of saving to temp file.

Comment: Yea, I saw in task manager, that the EXCEL.exe process is still working, but i thought maybe I am doing something wrong, maybe I am missing one line of openpyxl code :/
I will try `pandas` and come back, maybe with an answer :)

Comment: Don't use `pandas`, especially not if you're inserting images into a worksheet.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).